# PHP is calling a python script, but python create a *.cmd file

Tags: php, python-2.7

I have a PHP script by which I am calling a python script in this way:

```
$mystring = shell_exec('/programs/PYTHON2/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/znf_models.py -d givendna -j hbonds -m model');
```

In the python script I am calling an external program (called Chimera) that requires as input a *.cmd file. So, I am trying to write a cmd file as usual:

```
ZNF_chi = open("chimera_template.cmd", "w");
```

The problem is that the whole process freezes at this point. If I call my python script outside PHP there is no freezing. I have also tried to create a *.txt file with my PHP-python pipeline and there is no problem either. But I need to create cmd files instead of txt (for the Chimera program). Could you help me please? Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: are you sure of the curent directory when you're running the script? try to set an absolute path for your output file (somewhere you _really_ can write)

Comment: Indeed it was a problem of the "html" folder! Although I had changed the privileges it wasn't able to create there *.cmd files. I created a new "html" folder and it works. Thank you so much for your help!